# RabbitMQ Consumer Disconnect Event

Tags: events, rabbitmq, message

Is there any way we can know when a consumer disconnects from a queue or when a queue is deleted?

The requirement is as follows:

I'm building a system in which multiple clients can subscribe to certain events from the system. All clients create their own queue and registers themselves with the system using some sort of authentication. The system, as the events are generated, filters the events and forwards them to clients who are eligible for them.

I have implemented a POC for most part of it and it works well. An issue that I'm not able to fix is that, if a client just disconnects from the queue (due to program termination or so), the registration still exists and the system keeps trying to push messages to that client.

So we would like to be notified when a client disconnects or a queue gets deleted so that we can remove that client's registration data and no longer push messages to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your publisher utilize [Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements)](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) and make client queue be exclusive and transient, so only one client at a time will be consuming from one queue and after it disconnection it will be deleted.

If you publish message that get routed to only one queue and that queue gone (assume you utilize publisher confirms and publish message with `mandatory` flag set) publisher will be notified that message cannot be routed with that message returned back to it, so you can stop publishing messages.

For details see How Confirms Work section in [RabbitMQ blog post "Introducing Publisher Confirms"](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) and [Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements)](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) official docs.

Comment: it's a great idea. Also I found this plugin: rabbitmq_event_exchange. What are your ideas regarding using this community plugin?

Comment: I've never used it in production, but if they say it works why not just give a try?

Comment: I just implemented it in a POC and it seems to work just great. Very useful.